# Someone left a sefer open. Who is affected by increased forgetfulness?

Tags: jewish-books, memory

Amongst the things that [encourage forgetfulness דברים הגורמים   לשכחה](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%97%D7%94)   is

השארת ספר פתוח בעת הלימוד

leaving a book open at the time of learning.

Is the possibility of forgetfulness just for the person who left the book open or for anyone who sees it and does not close it?

Comment: http://www.chabad.org.il/Questions/PrintQuestion.asp?ArticleID=4491&CategoryID=68 according to what it says here, one should not close a Sefer that someone else left open, unless he reads/learns something from it himself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source for the comment on the wiki is the [Shach in SA YD 277](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.277.1?lang=he&with=Siftei%20Kohen&lang2=he), who confirms that there is an angel called "Shad" (Shamor Dapin) who causes:

> על **מי שמניח ספר פתוח ויוצא** שמשכח תלמודו
>
> on ***the one who leaves a sefer open* and goes out** to forget his Torah